# Word Macro to Count Words in Quotation Marks

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-count

I am writing my essays for university and I am not allowed to include words used in quotes toward my total word count. As Word does not have a feature to do this i was hoping that someone would be able to help me by creating a macro. I have used macros before, but I have very, very little experience into something as complex as this (if it's even that complex).

I already have something similar to work with citations throughout a document and so having both of these will be a great help. I will copy this code below so you can get a rough idea of what I need, except with quotes instead of citations.

So I was wondering if someone would be able to produce a macro that counted the number of words used in quotes throughout a document?

```
Sub CitationWordCount()

Dim Fld As Field, l As Long, StrTmp As String
For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  With Fld
    If .Type = wdFieldCitation Then
      StrTmp = .Result
      l = l + UBound(Split(StrTmp, " ")) + UBound(Split(StrTmp, "-")) + 1
      StrTmp = .Code.Text
      l = l + Len(StrTmp) - Len(Replace(StrTmp, "\n", "\"))
    End If
  End With
Next
MsgBox "There are " & l & " words in citations in this document.", , "Citation Word Count"
End Sub
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Where is the code you are using for citations?

Comment: Sorry, coding for citations now added!

Comment: *"if someone would be able to produce a macro that [...]"* - that's absolutely not what this site is about. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and the post link Scott linked to. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. "I have code that does X, I need code that does Y" is not a question asking about a specific programming issue and showing effort to solve the problem at hand (which is Y, not X). Look into researching about how regular expressions can help you extract matching quoted substrings from an input.

Comment: "So I was wandering if someone would be able to produce a macro that counted the number of words used in quotes throughout a document?" that is a question, if your answer is "no" then move on, don't bother leaving a comment

Comment: Again, read all the links provided. That is not a valid question on this site - FYI this site has an automated system that **will** question-ban you if you just keep asking such questions, I'm just trying to help you **not** getting yourself banned. The problem you need to solve is *locating matching quotes in an input string*, and this question shows zero research effort towards solving *that* problem. Oh and BTW my answer is "Yes I can write that, and no I'm not writing that for you here on this site for free, because that isn't what this site is for". Get it?

Answer (score -1):

Paul Edstein (macropod) wrote a solution to this issue months ago on http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/33866-count-words-between-quotation-marks.html

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  j = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "[“" & Chr(34) & "]*[" & Chr(34) & "”]"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      i = i + .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
    MsgBox "This document contains " & j & " words ," & vbCr & _
      "of which " & i & " (" & Format(i * 100 / j, "0.00") & _
      "%) are in quotes."
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will give you your total word count and the total amount of words in quotation marks. To get your total number, just subtract the words in quotes from the total words.

Comment: Thank you, i couldn't find anything when i looked. clearly didnt look hard enough

Comment: @Dom.Ibbz For anything Word VBA related, always, always go check the ms office forums - there are some true Word MVPs over there that have written almost anything and everything under the sun for Word (they're also very willing to write free code for you if you give them time).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll be sure to check there in the future!